# Docker hello-world: authentication error

Tags: docker, windows-10

I'm just getting started with docker. I'm following the instructions specified here https://docs.docker.com/windows/step_one/

I installed docker (1.10.2) on windows 10 & ran `docker run hello-world` . But, I'm getting an authentication error while the tutorial doesn't mentioned anything about it.

Here's the message I received.

```
$ docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Authentication is required: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/hello-world/manifests/latest: unauthorized: incorrect username or password.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.
```

I searched google & here, but couldn't find anything similar to this error message.

Thanks!

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Please run `docker login` at first time when you run any other docker commands.

> You can log into any public or private repository for which you have credentials. When you log in, the command stores encoded credentials in `$HOME/.docker/config.json` on Linux or`%USERPROFILE%/.docker/config.json` on Windows.

Comment: That Worked! Thanks. I wonder why they didn't mention a word about it in the documentation.

Comment: you can raise an issue to https://github.com/docker/docker/tree/master/docs and if you want to help, you can raise pull request to merge your fix to this open source project.

Comment: Sure. Will check it out.

Comment: But, should "docker login" be required prior to "docker run hello-world"? I have just tried this on a freshly installed Mac. I could run "docker run hello-world" without any "docker login" command prior to that.

Comment: I worked through K Scott Allen's tutorial on this without encountering a problem. However docker login has helped me subsequently.

Comment: Just had this problem, `docker login` solved it, but login failed with my full email as ID. Had to enter only username (MacOS Sierra)

Comment: For me the credential error occured even when doing docker login with right credentials. (First performed docker login, executed hello-world 3 times. and it worked. Then after som time, tried hello-world, it stated that I need to login. And then the same error shows then trying to login)

Comment: I tried docker login then docker run hello-world. It prompts for password. I pasted my docker password in on the terminal and then it shows the same error: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: unauthorized: incorrect username or password

Comment: Got it working now...when it shows: Username (user-name@domain.com): type in the user name and then it'll prompt for the password.

Comment: "docker login" did the trick , just remember that username is not same as email id, that was this silly mistake i was doing

Comment: It worked, thanks. 
Just use 'username' and 'password' that you used in 'hub.docker.com'.

Answer (score 38):

If you login through your emailId it does not works.

On windows login using your docker hub id.
[image]

You can access by your username.

Answer (score 13):

Probably it can happen if you were logged in before, by console or by kitematic.

You can try `docker logout` if you want use docker without auth.

In this case `Authentication is required:` shouldn't appear again.

Answer (score 5):

I have solved this issue in macOS Mojave (version : 10.14.3)

```
docker login
```

Login with your username not email id then its working fine.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

On macOS you need to login from the commandline using

`docker login`

Also you must use your username and not your email

Answer (score 4):

on ubuntu:

```
docker login
```

so if you don't know your username password, you probably haven't created one.
what you should do, is go and create an id on docker 
visit: [official docker webpage](https://www.docker.com/)

just like any other github accout ,they will ask you for the username, provide one and they will authenticate same as github, once done , put your email and password. verify it and you are now good to go.

ok! now coming to the point...
if you were facing the problem like the problem statement ,
just do

```
docker login
```

enter username and password, that you just provided .
you will be displayed ,"LOGIN  succeeded"

now run this command

```
docker run hello-world
```

beware of the dash '-' sign , i myself stuck with this issue, and you are done.

thanks:)

Answer (score 3):

run `docker login` to execute any other docker commands. or just logout if you want to use public hubs `docker logout`

Comment: For serverless.com deployments using serverless-python-requirements plugin, docker logout worked great, thank you.

Comment: Awesome, glad i am able to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

For worked trying `docker logout` and then `docker login` with the proper credentials

Answer (score 1):

For those who logged in via their `email` address associated with their account during the Docker desktop installation process - this problem seems to occur because the terminal has also stored those credentials, but for some reason it only accepts login's via your actual **`username`**.

If you go to DockerHub you should see it in the upper right corner.

Try running `docker login` with that username, and you should be all set!

```
docker login

# username from dockerhub
# the same password
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting my vNAT for docker dns server to 8.8.8.8 resolved my issue on windows just try might help thanks