# pull access denied repository does not exist or may require docker login

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04

I am using Laravel 4.2 with docker. I setup it on local. It worked without any problem but when I am trying to setup online using same procedure then I am getting error:

```
pull access denied for <projectname>/php, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

is it something relevant to create repository here https://cloud.docker.com/  or need to docker login in command?

After days of study I am still not able to figure out what could be the fix in this case and what are the right steps?

I have the complete code. I can paste here if need to check certain parts.

Comment: Sometimes it is just because you didn't build the required image. When you have both Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file in which you declared that there is one image that depends on another one (which is not built locally yet). So you need to `docker build` the needed image first.

Answer (score 192):

Please note that the error message from Docker is misleading.

```
$ docker build deploy/.
Sending build context to Docker daemon  5.632kB
Step 1/16 : FROM rhel7:latest
pull access denied for rhel7, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

It says *that it **may** require 'docker login'*.
I struggled with this.  I realized the image does not exist at https://hub.docker.com any more.

Comment: Or you are logged in with email address instead of docker id. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35644329/docker-hello-world-authentication-error/35644630#35644630

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. That error message is indeed very misleading since in my case the image simply didn't exist. But I had a remote repository configured that was not available at the time. So when docker couldn't find the image in my local repo, it tried that remote one and failed. It would be nice if docker displayed the name of the repository in the error, so you are aware what is happening under the covers.

Comment: In my case, I entered a wrong docker command-- which is the same as the image not existing in repo.

Comment: Thanks .. this is a very misleading error .. in my case, it was incorrect syntax .. .I didn't realize I had typed `docker create service` when the correct usage is  `docker service create`

Comment: The error is misleading. The image is simple missing. You might have to load image or in my case a I needed to run another Dockerfile to create the image needed by my next Dockerfile.

Comment: yes the error is misleading.... In my case it was a type instead of alpine I wrote apline

Comment: Like with @gaoithe, I also had to run an sh script to build an image from a Dockerfile. I did not know that and ran another starting sh script but that already needed the build sh script to be run before.

Comment: For me, I didn't realize I needed to preface detach with 2 dashes: `docker container run ... --detach ...`

Comment: For me `docker build -t image-name .` hade one image name and my `docker-compose.yml` had a different image name (typo)

Answer (score 66):

Just make sure to write the docker name correctly!

In my case, I wrote (notice the extra 'u'):

```
FROM ubunutu:16.04
```

The correct docker name is:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
```

Comment: I think they should just fix the spelling of "ubuntu" to the better "ubunutu" ;-)

Comment: Yes, misprint is most frequently case

Comment: Ha! In my case it was pyhon and not python.

Comment: In a similar vein, I wasn't running with the docker-compose file I thought I was, so check that too.

Comment: similar mistake. was using postgresql instead of postgres

Comment: Thanks! Had used alpine3.16 instead of alpine:3.16

Answer (score 29):

The message usually comes when you put the wrong image name. Please check your image if it exists on the Docker repository with the correct tag.
It helped me.

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name ngnix ngnix:latest
Unable to find image 'ngnix:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for ngnix, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
$ docker run -d -p 80:80 --name nginx nginx:latest
Unable to find image 'nginx:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/nginx
```

Comment: Same issue for me while incorrectly using `alpine3.17.4` instead of `alpine:3.17.4`. I've been searching forever, until I landed to you answer.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same issue. In my case it was a private registry. So I had to create a secret as shown [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)

and then we have to add the image pull secret to the deployment.yaml file as shown below.

```
pods/private-reg-pod.yaml  
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: private-reg
spec:
  containers:
  - name: private-reg-container
    image: <your-private-image>
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: regcred
```

Answer (score 14):

## November 2020 and later

If this error is new, and pulling from Docker Hub worked in the past, note [Docker Hub now introduced rate limiting in Nov 2020](https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limits)

You will frequently see messages like:

> Warning: No authentication provided, using CircleCI credentials for pulls from Docker Hub.

From Circle CI and other similar tools that use Docker Hub. Or:

> Error response from daemon: pull access denied for cimg/mongo, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

You'll need to specify the credentials used to fetch the image:

For [CircleCI users](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/private-images/):

```
      - image: circleci/mongo:4.4.2

        # Needed to pull down Mongo images from Docker hub
        # Get from https://hub.docker.com/
        # Set up at https://app.circleci.com/pipelines/github/org/sapp
        auth:
          username: $DOCKERHUB_USERNAME
          password: $DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD
```

Comment: I did this, set up the username and password as environment variables on circleci console for my project and it's still telling me `Error response from daemon: pull access denied for nyck33/myimage, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied`

Answer (score 10):

I solved this by inserting a language at the front of the docker image

FROM **python**:3.7-alpine

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue

```sh
pull access denied for microsoft/mmsql-server-linux, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Turns out the [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/) was moved to a different name
So I would suggest you re check-in docker hub

Comment: worked like a charm for me, u saved my day. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

In my case I was using a custom image and docker baked into Minikube on my local machine.

I had specified the pull policy incorrectly:-

```
imagePullPolicy: Always
```

But it should have been:-

```
imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Because the custom image was only present locally after I'd explicitly built it in the minikube docker environment.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error message but for a totally different reason.

Being new to docker, I issued

> docker run -it <crypticalId>

where <crypticalId> was the id of my newly created container.

But, the run command wants the id of an *image*, not a container.

To start a container, docker wants

> docker **start** -i <crypticalId>

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue when working with docker-composer. In my case it was an Amazon AWS ECR private registry. It seems to be a bug in docker-compose

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1622#issuecomment-162988389

After adding the full path "myrepo/myimage" to docker compose yaml

> image: xxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myrepo:myimage

it was all fine.

Answer (score 6):

I had this because I inadvertantly remove the AS tag from my first image:

ex:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1607-KB4546850-amd64
...
.. etc ...
...
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1607-KB4546850-amd64
COPY --from=installer ["/dotnet", "/Program Files/dotnet"]
... etc ...
```

should have been:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1607-KB4546850-amd64 AS installer
...
.. etc ...
...
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1607-KB4546850-amd64
COPY --from=installer ["/dotnet", "/Program Files/dotnet"]
... etc ...
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it made me look again my dockerfile and realized that I made this same mistake hehe.

Answer (score 4):

if you have over two stage in the docker build process read this solution:
this error message is completely misleading.

if you have a two-stage (context) dockerfile and want to copy some data from the first to the second stage, you must label the first context (ex: build) and access it by that label

```
#stage(1)
from <image> as build 
.
.
#stage(2)
From <image>
copy --from=build /sourceDir  /distinationDir
```

Comment: Bravo!!! Spot on!!

Answer (score 3):

If the repository is private you have to assign permissions to download it. You have two options, with the docker login command, or put in ~/.docker/docker.config the file generated once you login.

Comment: It is working fine on local. Why it is creating error online?

Comment: I have logged in using docker login but I could not find ~/.docker/docker.config

Comment: ~/.docker/docker.config works only in linux, are you running docker for mac o for windows  ???

Comment: I am running for Ubuntu 16.0.4

Comment: Did you try with ```docker login --username user --password pass``` ???
did you try with the pull path
```docker pull registry.hub.docker.com/organization/image:version ``` ???

Comment: @Jass Sorry it is a bit late, but can you please show how do you manage to run it on a local kube cluster ? Are you using Minikube or the Docker Edge's kube cluster ?

Answer (score 3):

Docker might have lost the authentication data. So you'll have to reauthenticate with your registry provider. With AWS for example:

```
aws ecr get-login --region us-west-2 --no-include-email
```

And then copy and paste that resulting "docker login..." to authenticated docker.

Source: [Amazon ECR Registeries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/Registries.html#registry_auth)

Comment: In my case, the registry was placed in Google Cloud, and I was logged out of my gcloud account. 

I noticed in config.json, the credHelpers keys and values, for example:


"credHelpers": {
  "asia.gcr.io": "gcloud"
}

This suggested that I may need to log in to my gcloud account. Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 3):

This error message might possibly indicate something else.

In my case I defined another Docker-Image elsewhere from which the current Docker inherited its settings (`docker-compos.yml`):

```
FROM my_own_image:latest
```

The error message I got:

```
qohelet$ docker-compose up
Building web
Step 1/22 : FROM my_own_image:latest
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: pull access denied for my_own_image, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

Due to a reinstall the previous Docker were gone and I couldn't build my docker using `docker-compose up` with this command:

```
sudo docker build -t my_own_image:latest -f MyOwnImage.Dockerfile .
```

In your specific case you might have defined your own php-docker.

Answer (score 3):

I had to run docker pull first, then running docker-compose up again and then it worked.

```
docker pull index.docker.io/youruser/yourrepo:latest
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was following Dapr + docker-compose docks and they don't mention anything about docker pull first

Answer (score 2):

If you're downloading from somewhere else than your own registry or docker-hub, you might have to do a separate agreement of terms on their site, like the case with Oracle's docker registry. It allows you to do docker login fine, but pulling the container won't still work until you go to their site and agree on their terms.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the `image` exists in docker hub. To me, I was trying to pull MongoDB using the command `docker run mongodb` which is incorrect. In the docker hub, the image name is `mongo`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have an image with that name locally, docker will try to pull it from docker hub, but there's no such image on docker hub.
Or simply try "docker login".

Answer (score 2):

If you are using multiple Dockerfiles you should not forget to run build for all of it. That was my case.

Answer (score 2):

## For private repo.

use this patten `username/image:tag`

example, rohitnishad613 is my docker usernam

```
rohitnishad/some-app:latest
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your docker-compose.yml file

```
image: php:rc-zts-alpine
```

Answer (score 1):

I heard the same issue.
I solved by login

```
docker login -u your_user_name
```

then I was prompt to enter docker hub password
The rest command work perfect after login successfull

Answer (score 1):

### Exceeded Docker Hub's Limit on Free Repos:

Despite first executing:

```
docker login -u <dockerhub uname>
```

and "*Login Succeeded*" being returned, I received the error in this question.

In the webgui in ***Settings*** > ***Visibility Settings*** I remarked:

> Using 2 of 1 private repositories.

Which told me that I had exceeded the limit on Docker Hub's free account limits. However, removing a previous image didn't clear the error...

### The Fix:

Indeed, the error message in my case was a red herring- it's nothing related to authentication issues.

Deleting just the images ***exceeding*** the allowed limit did **NOT** clear the error however!

To get past the error you need to delete **ALL** the images in your **FREE** Docker Hub account, then run a new build pushing the image to your account.

Your `pull` command will now succeed.

Answer (score 1):

> ERROR [server internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/base:latest

In my case, my Dockerfile was using multiple stages, and one of them was referencing a stage name that didn't exist.

```
FROM <image-name>

# ...

FROM base AS development # I forgot to ad "AS base" above
```

Answer (score 1):

Also happens in multistage builds if you referenced a non-existent stage. For example

`COPY --from=previous-stage /foo/bar /foo/bar`

Comment: this was the error for me. solved, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When I run the command multiple times "docker pull scrapinghub/splash" in Power shell then it solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

if it was caused with AWS EC2 and ECR, due to name issue(happens with beginners!)

Error response from daemon: pull access denied for my-app, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied

when using docker pull use Image URI of the image, available in ECR-row itself as Copy URI

```
docker pull Image_URI
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this message and thought something was wrong about my Docker authentication. However, I've realized that Docker only allows 1 private repository per free plan. So it is quite possible that you are trying to pull your private repository and see this error because have not upgraded your plan.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem but nothing worked. And then I understood I need run `.sh` (`.ps1`) script first before doing `docker-compose`.

So I have the following files:

```
   docker-compose.yml
   
   docker-build.sh
   
   docker-build.ps1
   
   Dockerfile
```

And I had to first run `docker-build.sh` on Unix (Mac) machine or `docker-build.ps1` on Windows:

```
sh docker-build.sh
```

It will build an image in my case.
And only then after an image has been built I can run:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

For references. Here is my `docker-compose` file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  api-service:
    image: x86_64/prediction-service:0.8.1
    container_name: api-service
    expose:
      - 8060
    ports:
      - "8060:80"
```

And here is `docker-build.sh`:

```
VERSION="0.8.1"
ARCH="x86_64"
APP="prediction-service"
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"
docker build -f $DIR/Dockerfile -t $ARCH/$APP:$VERSION .
```

Answer (score 0):

I had misspelled nginx to nignx in Dockerfile

Comment: And it gave you this error? That seems unexpected?

Comment: @JeremyCaney Yes, it did

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to re-create docker-file through visual studio and all worked perfeclty.

Answer (score 0):

Someone might come across the same error for different reasons than what is already presented, so let me share:

I got the same error when using docker multistage builds (Multiple: FROM <> as <>).
And I forgot to remove one (COPY --from=<> <>)

After removing that COPY then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, none of the provided solutions helped. For me a Login was necessary, but I spend a couple of time figuring out that I have to add the Server Path to the pull command:

```
docker login registry-1.docker.io -u <DOCKER_USERNAME> -p <DOCKER_ACCESS_TOKEN>
docker pull registry-1.docker.io/<DOCKER_USERNAME>/<REPO_TAG>:latest
```

The Server registry-1.docker.io is the default Servername of Docker Hub

Answer (score 0):

I had to re-build the container! Nothing else worked for me.

```
docker run build <imagename>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was working fine locally. And was working for one instance of a GitHub Action but failing for another one for no apparent reason. I made a change to free disk space on the runner, thinking that might have been related to the issue and it now works:

```
    ...
    steps:
    # Source: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/free-disk-space-ubuntu
    - name: Free Disk Space (Ubuntu)
      uses: jlumbroso/free-disk-space@main

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this very easily when I was trying to run the image on an m1 mac but had built the image for `amd` architecture instead, rebuilding the image with the correct architecture worked like a charm

```
docker build --platform linux/arm64 -t docker-image:test .
```

replace `arm64` with `amd64` for intel architecture

Answer (score 0):

Experienced this mystery issue when trying to locally test my `AWS Lambda` image function built using `AWS CDK` and `AWS SAM`. You need to run `sam build` first, according to [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-cdk-building.html).

Try this:

```
cdk synth --no-staging > template.yaml && 
sam build -t template.yaml && 
sam local invoke -t template.yaml addToSearch
```