# docker pull voting-app throws access to the resource is denied error

Tags: docker

An attempt to pull the voting-app image throws resource denied error.

```
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for voting-app, the repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

could I have a solution to it, please?

Comment: Is the container image present in DockerHub?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pull access denied repository does not exist or may require docker login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48719921/pull-access-denied-repository-does-not-exist-or-may-require-docker-login)

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, it is clear that either the image you are trying to pull is not present in DockerHub or you need to login into your DockerHub account.

1. If image not present in DockerHub, first push your image into DockerHub, then only you can pull it.

```
$ docker push yourDockerHubAccountName/voting-app
$ docker pull voting-app
```

2. Login into your DockerHub account:

```
docker login --username=yourHubUserName --email=yourRegisteredEmail@provider.com
```

You will be prompted for password on the bash screen. Enter your password to access all the public images ever uploaded on DockerHub.