# Starting ssh service through ENTRYPOINT not working

Tags: docker, ssh

I'm having a lot of difficulties running an linux container with SSH service on it. To skip the details, SSH is not optional, I must have it.

I installed the openssh-server with:

> RUN 
> echo "**** Setting up openssh-server ****" &&
> apt-get install -y openssh-server &&
> sed -i "s|#   PasswordAuthentication yes|PasswordAuthentication yes|g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config &&
> mkdir /var/run/sshd

And am trying to open the service with:

> ENTRYPOINT service ssh restart && bash

However it does not work. I tried in multiple way to get it started, by using CMD, by making a script that would start the service, and it's not working. What's worse is that this seems to have worked for others ([pull access denied repository does not exist or may require docker login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48719921/pull-access-denied-repository-does-not-exist-or-may-require-docker-login))

The image that I am using as base is ubuntu:18.04. However I switched to jre/systemd-ubuntu:18.04 as I thought the lack of systemd could prevent the service from running however that did not work either. Any suggestions what the possibly issue could be?

Comment: You don't need `systemd`. You can run the service in the foreground (`-D`) and output debug logs to stderr (`-e`). [Here is an `ubunutu:18.04` based `openssh-server` image](https://github.com/masseybradley/openssh-server/blob/master/openssh-server/Dockerfile) if that helps.

Comment: This doesn't do anything it seems. I get no error messages printed and the service is still not running ...

Comment: Unclear what you tried exactly. e.g. I use my image(s) in production, they work fine.

Comment: I have rebuilt the image using the command `ENTRYPOINT /usr/sbin/sshd -D -e' as in the linked image but no output is received. I stand corrected, the service does work now, provided there's not a non-returning service running in the container beforehand

Comment: Cool that you got it working. Correct, e.g. just setting the `ENTRYPOINT` (any `ENTRYPOINT`) won't solve anything if the image itself isn't correct (`openssh-server` won't start if host keys are missing or `/var/run/sshd` doesn't exist - [I use a `VOLUME` to make sure that directory is created](https://github.com/masseybradley/openssh-server/blob/master/openssh-server/Dockerfile#L9)).

Comment: My guess is at the start it did not work because of that, then I added this file however I had other changes that broke the image :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get my service to run, as a first advice I recommend making sure that the service runs by itself before putting it together with other services. In my case it seems the ssh service was not being started because a previous non-returning service was started which would keep the shell occupied and would not let it continue it's `ENTRYPOINT` execution to start the SSH.

One other thing that I had done previously and could have been part of the solution is that I manually created the folder `/var/run/sshd`. It seems some ssh service versions need that to exist otherwise they won't run. At this point I can't verify though if that was the only issue, as I've tried multiple solution at once.