# Error using cuda 11.2 along with Ubuntu 20.04 image in docker

Tags: docker, cuda

I am trying to use a base image for docker using Ubuntu 20.04 and Cuda 11.2 (as it is on my machine) to be used with tensorflow 2.5.

I modified a previous version of Ubuntu 18.04 I had. This dockerfile works fine:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.0-runtime-ubuntu18.04
CMD nvidia-smi
```

but this one does not (which is a direct transcription of the previous one):

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.2-runtime-ubuntu20.04
CMD nvidia-smi
```

> manifest for nvidia/cuda:11.2-runtime-ubuntu20.04 not found: manifest
> unknown: manifest unknown

neither do this:

```
FROM nvidia/11.2.0-runtime-ubuntu18.04
CMD nvidia-smi
```

> pull access denied for nvidia/11.2.0-runtime-ubuntu18.04, repository
> does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access
> to the resource is denied

I concluded that this is the case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54130954/3584765): there is no relevant image to the docker server since the message is misleading. But in the [documentation](https://gitlab.com/nvidia/container-images/cuda/blob/master/doc/supported-tags.md#cuda-1120-1) is appears valid.

The same is true about this one:

```
FROM nvidia/11.2.0-runtime-ubuntu20.04
CMD nvidia-smi
```

So, can someone provide some advice over how can I use a cuda 11.2+Ubuntu 20.04 image?

Answer (score 2):

Basically all of the examples except the first one are referring to non-existent images.

Here is a wrong version number:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.2-runtime-ubuntu20.04
```

Here you've lost image name (`cuda`):

```
FROM nvidia/11.2.0-runtime-ubuntu18.04
```

Should be `cuda:11.2.0-...`:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.2.0-runtime-ubuntu20.04
```

The list of available versions is available at [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/cuda/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated&name=11.2.0-runtime-ubuntu20.04). Also, instead of using Dockerfile, you can check if an image exists with this short command:

```sh
sudo docker run --rm --gpus all nvidia/cuda:11.2.0-runtime-ubuntu20.04 nvidia-smi
```

Answer (score 1):

The image you are looking for is available [here](https://hub.docker.com/layers/nvidia/cuda/11.2.0-runtime-ubuntu20.04/images/sha256-0edea12db78150a10bbd97ed4528ca080403902434249b4421b59a591a969d19?context=explore).

You have missed to add the proper image name. It should be `nvidia/cuda:11.2.0-runtime-ubuntu20.04`. You have missed the `cuda:` part.