# Running docker first test

Tags: docker

I am a beginner to the docker technology, as I have downloaded it, the program doesn't launch. i Tested Docker --version and shows Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a.

I tried docker run hello-world as it appears in the tutorial, it shows the following error that i couldn't understand and fix, :

Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/hello-world/manifests/latest: unauthorized: incorrect username or password.

any guide and better tutorial for fixing such problems and get improved with following step by step the technology and work on it?

**Edit: Problem Solved!**

in command line i have login and it was the key point where i get to run the test image.

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker hello-world: authentication error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35644329/docker-hello-world-authentication-error)

Comment: @Tuxpilgrim   windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try create an [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/) account. Then in your machine, type `docker login`. Then login by dockerhub account you just create... This should work.

Comment: Great! thank you a lot it works! sad that such a simple valuable information is not mentioned in the tutorial at the official website.